# TDD: how to verify method calls made from a list of objects in Java?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, mockito

I have a class FileGenerator, and I'm writing a test for the generateFile() method that should do the following:

1) it should call the static method getBlockImpl(FileTypeEnum) on BlockAbstractFactory

2) it should populate variable blockList from the subclass method getBlocks()

3) it should call a static method createFile from a final helper class FileHelper passing a String parameter

4) it should call the run method of each BlockController in the blockList

I'm trying to use TDD to test the last scenario of my method. I have a list of BlockController objects that implement Runnable, and I need to verify if each one calls the run() method.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public class FileGenerator {
// private fields with Getters and Setters

    public void generateBlocks() {
        // 1,2 get the block manager that will return the BlockController list
        blockManager = BlockAbstractFactory.getManager(fileType);
        blockList = blockManager.getBlocks();
        // create a file using FileHelper
        FileHelper.createFile(path);

        // What I want to test:
        // for each BlockController in the blockList, call the run() method
    }
}
```

I am using Junit and Mockito. In the Mockito's documentation, they only show how to mock a List and verify method calls on the List (such as add(T), remove(T) etc), not its objects.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer before I posted the question. It's actually quite simple.

First, you need to mock the object you'll have using Mockito:

```
final BlockController mockedBlock = mock(BlockController.class);
```

Next, create the List using your mocked object (below I have create a list of 3 mocked objects of type BlockController):

```
List<BlockController> myBlockList = Arrays.asList(mockedBlock, mockedBlock, mockedBlock);
```

Set the list in your tested class to the list of mocked objects before calling the method:

```
fileGenerator.setBlockList(myBlockList);
fileGenerator.generateBlocks();
```

Now, with Mockito, just verify if the number of calls to the bar method match the size of your List:

```
verify( myBlockList, times(myBlockList.size()) ).run();
```

This is what it looks like in the end (my FileGenerator object is created in a @Before method):

```
@Test
public testShouldCallRunForEachBlock() {
    final BlockController mockedBlock = mock(BlockController.class);
    List<BlockController> myBlockList = Arrays.asList(mockedBlock, mockedBlock, mockedBlock);

    fileGenerator.setBlockList(myBlockList);
    fileGenerator.generateBlocks();

    verify( myBlockList, times(myBlockList.size()) ).run();
}
```

And that's it. Now the test will fail until the a loop is implemented.